# How to indent items in LaTeX/AUCTeX itemize environments?

Tags: indentation, latex, auctex

**Q:** how can I get "proper" indentation of LaTeX `itemize` environments in `auctex`?

Here's where I'd like to be with an `item` in an `itemize` environment:

- `\item` line is indented two spaces relative to the beginning of the environment
- continuation lines in the item are indented an additional two spaces relative to the `\item` line

This is what I would like/expect to see:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item Here's a really long item in a LaTeX itemize environment;
    note how the *initial* item line is indented two spaces, and the
    continuation lines are indented another two spaces.
\end{itemize}
```

One can adjust the initial indentation of the item with the `LaTeX-item-indent` variable, which defaults to `-2`.  With this default, I get the undesirable behavior of the `\item` not being indented, but I *do* get the desired behavior of the continuation lines being offset by an additional two spaces:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Here's a really long item in a LaTeX itemize environment;
  note how the *initial* item line is *NOT* indented two spaces,
  but the continuation lines are indented two spaces.
\end{itemize}
```

Setting `LaTeX-item-indent` to `0` gets me the desired indentation on the `\item` line (two spaces in), but does *not* get me the second half of the desired behavior of the continuation lines being offset by an additional two spaces:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item Here's a really long item in a LaTeX itemize environment;
  note how the *initial* item line is indented two spaces, but the
  continuation lines are *NOT* indented an additional two spaces.
\end{itemize}
```

So: how does one get *both* desired behaviors:

- initial indent of the `\item` line two spaces, and
- continuation lines an additional two spaces indented?

(Note [Related SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477195/latex-indentation-formatting-in-emacs).)

Comment: I've been messing around with this exact issue for a couple of hours; your first method works if you also set `LaTeX-indent-level` to 4. Items will be indented to 4 - 2 = 2 and continuation lines will be indented to 4 = 2 + 2. However, this does mean that every other environment in the file will be indented to 4 (and not 2), which may or may not be desirable. I'd rather they be indented at 2 themselves, which is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Did you try customizing `LaTeX-indent-environment-list` and adding a custom function for indentation?  The function `LaTeX-indent-tabular` might provide a reasonable starting point (or at least a reasonable example of customized indentation within an environment).  I just stumbled across this variable/function, so I haven't had a chance to look into it myself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@sykora's comment about `(setq LaTeX-item-indent -2 LaTeX-indent-level 4)` is almost there, but it does mean we spill over to every other environment as well.  So, for example, we would also have:

```
\begin{abstract}
    This indents to the 4th column, which is way too far!
\end{abstract}
```

The following function builds off an old (and seemingly broken?) code snippet from [Tassilo Horn](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.auctex.general/5182).  It gets the indentation correct, including for nested environments.  It works for `itemize`, `enumerate`, and `description` environments, to boot:

```
(defun LaTeX-indent-item ()
  "Provide proper indentation for LaTeX \"itemize\",\"enumerate\", and
\"description\" environments.

  \"\\item\" is indented `LaTeX-indent-level' spaces relative to
  the the beginning of the environment.

  Continuation lines are indented either twice
  `LaTeX-indent-level', or `LaTeX-indent-level-item-continuation'
  if the latter is bound."
  (save-match-data
    (let* ((offset LaTeX-indent-level)
           (contin (or (and (boundp 'LaTeX-indent-level-item-continuation)
                            LaTeX-indent-level-item-continuation)
                       (* 2 LaTeX-indent-level)))
           (re-beg "\\\\begin{")
           (re-end "\\\\end{")
           (re-env "\\(itemize\\|\\enumerate\\|description\\)")
           (indent (save-excursion
                     (when (looking-at (concat re-beg re-env "}"))
                       (end-of-line))
                     (LaTeX-find-matching-begin)
                     (current-column))))
      (cond ((looking-at (concat re-beg re-env "}"))
             (or (save-excursion
                   (beginning-of-line)
                   (ignore-errors
                     (LaTeX-find-matching-begin)
                     (+ (current-column)
                        (if (looking-at (concat re-beg re-env "}"))
                            contin
                          offset))))
                 indent))
             ((looking-at (concat re-end re-env "}"))
              indent)
            ((looking-at "\\\\item")
             (+ offset indent))
            (t
             (+ contin indent))))))

(defcustom LaTeX-indent-level-item-continuation 4
  "*Indentation of continuation lines for items in itemize-like
environments."
  :group 'LaTeX-indentation
  :type 'integer)

(eval-after-load "latex"
  '(setq LaTeX-indent-environment-list
         (nconc '(("itemize" LaTeX-indent-item)
                  ("enumerate" LaTeX-indent-item)
                  ("description" LaTeX-indent-item))
                LaTeX-indent-environment-list)))
```

I can't help but feel that there is a very simple setting I'm missing and this is the [Rube Goldberg](http://www.rubegoldberg.com/) version.  Still, it works, and it scratches an itch I've had for *years*.

**EDIT:** in response to @sykora's comment, I have revised the function to take out the hard coding.  `\item`s are now indented `LaTeX-indent-level` spaces.  Continuation lines can take the value of a new variable, `LaTeX-indent-level-item-continuation`, or, if you don't want to bind the latter, twice the value of `LaTeX-indent-level`.

As it happens, binding and setting `LaTeX-indent-level-item-continuation` to 8 gives aesthetically-pleasing results.  I might even switch to it:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item Example with LaTeX-indent-level-item-continuation set to 8.
  \item Here's a really long item that will spill over onto the
        continuation line; text lines up pretty nicely this way!
        \begin{itemize} 
          \item And here's a sub-item, with the environment
                indented to the relevant continuation line.
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: I spent a little time looking at it this morning, but needed to focus on something else.  I think line 3060 of `latex.el` -- i.e., `(+ (LaTeX-indent-calculate-last force-type) LaTeX-item-indent))` -- is contributing to the level of indent.

Comment: I just took it for a test ride, and it seems to perform pretty well -- thanks! If possible, you could replace the hard-coded 2s with either `LaTeX-indent-level` or a new variable -- `LateX-item-continuation-indent`?

Comment: @sykora: good suggestion!  Incorporated.

Comment: As a frequent TeXer, this is *fantastic*.  It's really always bugged me!  Thanks :)

Comment: What wrapping mode are you using here? I get every line flushed left. See http://i61.tinypic.com/eq8n7b.jpg

Comment: @NVaughan: try `newline-and-indent` rather than `TeX-newline`.

Comment: @Dan: Doesn't work. I am using `visual-line-mode` and I just get a new line flushed left. Are you using `adaptative-wrap-mode`?

Comment: @NVaughan: I'm not using `adaptive-wrap-mode`, but I think I might be seeing the problem that you're having.  Try `(setq TeX-newline-function #'LaTeX-newline)` (that, at any rate, cleared up the problem for me).

Comment: @Dan: No, I don't know what's going on, but it doesn't work. The only way I can obtain that result is by using `adaptative-wrap` (which I don't really like as it messes up the indentation of LaTeX environments).

Comment: @Dan Thank you for this. But is it just me, or does this break `fill-paragraph` in `\item`s?

Comment: @JasonMorgan: correct, `fill-paragraph` does not work here.  Long story, but the innards of the fill function for latex are pretty ugly, and I haven't had the time to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: @Dan Thank you. That is good to know. Now I won't spend hours trying to figure out what's wrong with my `.emacs` file.

Comment: Rube Goldberg link seems to be not related to emacs