# indent items in auctex

Tags: indentation, auctex, fill-paragraph, environment

What I would like to achieve is a deeper indentation of lines in `item`s in Auctex.

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item This is what I would like to achieve. The beginning of the
        second line aligns with the beginning of the item content
\end{itemize}
```

This is the standard behaviour

```
\begin{itemize}
\item This is what I current get. The beginning of the
  second line aligns with \item instead
\end{itemize}
```

There is a solution posted [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3083/how-to-indent-items-in-latex-auctex-itemize-environments) but it unfortunately breaks LaTeX-fill-paragraph (M-q) which is not acceptable to me.

Comment: FWIW, the "plain" `latex-mode` that comes with Emacs does an in-between where the line after `\item` is indented by 2 characters.

Comment: Thanks, but can I use it without switching mode?

Comment: @Stefan - With AUCTeX, `\item` is not indented, the line after it is indented by 2 characters.

Comment: @ArashEsbati: Ah, so AUCTeX does it just like plain latex-mode, and it's user52366's example which is off?

Comment: @Stefan - Yes, the snippet above advertised as `standard behaviour' is off.